# Echo and echo in PHP

Tags: php

How to echo the code below in php?

```
<a href="cust_room/assign_room.php?cust_id=<?php echo $row_customer['cust_id']; ?>">Assign Room</a>
```

I did try this, but got an error.

```
echo "<a href=\"cust_room/assign_room.php?cust_id=<?php echo $row_customer['cust_id']; ?>\">Assign Room</a>";
```

Answer (score 3):

try cause :`echo` inside another echo ! use concat to echo values inside `$row_customer['cust_id']`

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"cust_room/assign_room.php?cust_id=".$row_customer['cust_id'] ."\">Assign Room</a>"; ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

you cant use `<?php` in side `<?php`

try the following code:

```
echo "<a href=\"cust_room/assign_room.php?cust_id={$row_customer['cust_id']}\">Assign Room</a>";
```

instead of:

```
echo "<a href=\"cust_room/assign_room.php?cust_id=<?php echo $row_customer['cust_id']; ?>\">Assign Room</a>";
```

Comment: @JohnnyJ3T Welcome to stackoverflow. If this answer helped then please accept the answer.