# Echo parse error for creating new php file

Tags: php

Im creating a new php site with this script.
I try everything to get `$_POST['name']` into the new generated PHP site.

```
$myFile = "art.php";    
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); 
$stringData = "<span>" . echo $_POST['name']; . "</span>";


fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```

PHP always tells me that there is an parse error. When I delete the PHP code everything works as expected. I also tried:

```
$stringData = "<span>" . echo 'test' . "</span>";
```

So basically every php code I try to add doesn't work.

Comment: You can't echo inside of a string assignment. And a semi-colon completely ends the statement.

Comment: You don't use `echo` inside string concatenation. Neither do you use a `;` there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35861929/echo-and-echo-in-php/35861959#35861959

Comment: Im sorry for the duplicate, I looked at them and tried but it didn't worked for an hour im thankful for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

`$stringData = "<span>" . echo $_POST['name']; . "</span>";`

To:

`$stringData = "<span>" . $_POST['name'] . "</span>";`

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
$myFile = "art.php";    
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); 
$name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
$stringData = "<span>$name</span>";


fwrite($fh, $stringData);
fclose($fh);
```